# Difference or relationship between stack memory and mcache in go?

Tags: go, memory, goroutine, allocator

Now I'm learning go memory management, when allocating a small object, the allocator will look in the  corresponding mspan in mcache, and we also know goroutine has a stack memory, so does that mean the spans in mcache belongs to stack memory(not heap)?  What happened in memory if we define a varible in a func like `a := 1`?

Comment: How memory is managed is not specified by the language may change from compiler to compiler and even be different in each version.

Comment: @Volker correctly pointed it out. These things are susceptible to change. Still, you can read this article (based on go 1.13), I found it quite informative https://medium.com/a-journey-with-go/go-memory-management-and-allocation-a7396d430f44

Comment: It's stored either in stack or in heap. Stack belongs to goroutine while mcache belongs to os thread's processor. Where it may be placed? We can't to predict with a 100% confidence, use escape analyzer. Also read this: https://golang.org/s/go11sched

Answer (score 0):

this might be helpful https://go101.org/article/memory-block.html.

Also you can see what exact allocation is happening in memory using

```
go build -gcflags=-m your_file.go
```

Only things which used dynamically those only assigned to the heap.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func f() *int {
    var x int
    return &x
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(f())
}
```

---

go build -gcflags=-m encyptionDecryption.go

```
./encyptionDecryption.go:5:6: can inline f
./encyptionDecryption.go:11:15: inlining call to f
./encyptionDecryption.go:7:9: &x escapes to heap
./encyptionDecryption.go:6:6: moved to heap: x
./encyptionDecryption.go:11:15: f() escapes to heap
./encyptionDecryption.go:11:15: &x escapes to heap
./encyptionDecryption.go:11:15: moved to heap: x
./encyptionDecryption.go:11:13: main ... argument does not escape
```

This is escape analysis. You can read more [here](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2017/05/language-mechanics-on-escape-analysis.html)